# Typecasting issue when using EF.CompileAsyncQuery with Func in C# for returning nullable type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0, ef-core-7.0

I'm encountering a typecasting error while using EF.CompileAsyncQuery to define a function that should return a nullable type (Memo?). The code snippet I'm working with is as follows:

```
public static readonly Func<AppDbContext, int, int, CancellationToken, Task<Memo?>> GetDataByIdAsync =
    EF.CompileAsyncQuery((AppDbContext appDbContext, int memoId, int Id, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
         appDbContext.Set<Memo>()
            .Include(d => d.FocusAreas)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.MemoId == memoId && d.CreateUserId == Id, cancellationToken)
    );
```

The error I'm encountering is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Func<Infrastructure.Data.AppDbContext, int, int, System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Infrastructure.Entities.Memo>>>' to 'System.Func<Infrastructure.Data.AppDbContext, int, int, System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Infrastructure.Entities.Memo?>>'

I'm unsure about how to resolve this issue. How can I modify the code to ensure that the returned type aligns with the nullable Memo? type?

Can anyone please help me here by providing their guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the non-async version of the materialization operation:

```
public static readonly Func<AppDbContext, int, int, CancellationToken, Task<Memo?>> GetDataByIdAsync =
    EF.CompileAsyncQuery((AppDbContext appDbContext, int memoId, int Id, CancellationToken _) =>
      appDbContext.Set<Memo>()
        .Include(d => d.FocusAreas)
        .FirstOrDefault(d => d.MemoId == memoId && d.CreateUserId == Id));
```

The [EF.CompileAsyncQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.compileasyncquery?view=efcore-7.0) overloads accept a `Expression<Func<..., TResult>>` for `queryExpression`, not `Expression<Func<..., Task<TResult>>>`

Comment: Thanks @Guru Stron for the response. The above code is not using CancellationToken. Does it mean that we cannot use CancellationToken with EFCore compiled queries

Comment: @santoshkumarpatro no, it does not mean that. The expression you are providing will not be executed directly, as far as I understand, it seems that EF design team decided to use the  `CancellationToken` parameter in `queryExpression` to distinguish between the cancellable and non-cancellable overloads, hence the `CancellationToken` parameter of `queryExpression` is a dummy one. Based on quick peek - the cancellation token passed to the returned function should be used when actual query is perfromed.

Comment: Thanks @Guru Stron for the detailed explanation. I am able to fix the issue now :)